# Inserting data from form into database with OOP

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to insert data from a form into my database in an object-oriented fashion, but the data just isn't inserted. Why not?

```
class users {
    var $username;
    var $password;
    var $conection;
    var $tablename = usertable;

    function mysqldb() {
        $this->conection = mysql_connect("local host", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("this->tablename");
    }

    function insertdb() {
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $this->tablename values ('', '$user', '$pass')");
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if(!$result) die("Query didn't work. " . mysql_error());
    }
}

$user1 = new users;
$user1->username = $_POST["user"];
$user1->password = $_POST["pass"];
$user1->insertdb();
```

Comment: Please make an effort to at least type complete words and sentences. It shows you care :)

Comment: Almost definitely, you mean to connect to `localhost`, not `local host` -- not the space was removed.

Comment: its my very first post on stalkoverflow,still learning to modify  my code according to required format.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that your hostname is wrong.  Use `localhost`, not `local host`.

Now, you need to be escaping your data, otherwise you will run into trouble!  I suggest completely throwing out what you have in terms of `mysql_` functions, and [learn to do prepared queries with PDO](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html).

Answer (score 1):

after you instanciate your class, you call for the method insertdb(), but nowhere you connect to your database. You must call mysqldb() before!

Answer (score 0):

You have `mysql_select_db("this->tablename")`

you need `mysql_select_db($this->tablename)`

That's at least the immediate problem I see. You should really check into [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) which has the ability to fetch data into classes and objects. It's better practice all around.

Comment: no. mysql_select_db($string) excepts string as parameter. In this case, "$this->tablename" === $this->tablename => true as they both evaluates as string type

Comment: @Rasim Fryal's code has `this->tablename` note the missing `$`. So you are right but that isn't what he posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->conection = mysql_connect("local host", "root", "")
```

The `local host` should be `localhost`.

---

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $this->tablename values ('', '$user', '$pass')");
```

Neither of the last two variables are defined - you probably meant `$this->username` and `$this->password`. You're also probably opening yourself right up to some SQL injection vulnerabilities - check out PDO and prepared statements. And if this is for an actual web application, start salting and hashing your passwords.

---

```
mysql_select_db("this->tablename");
```

The `"this->tablename"` should be `$this->tablename`.

---

You also never call `mysqldb()` in the first place; you need to do that before attempting to insert into the database.

```
$user1->mysqldb();
```

Comment: thank u,i corrected local host into localhost ,called mysqldb() and $ to "this->tablename". but still data is not inserted

Comment: @RasimFryal: Can you update the post with your new code, please? Also, make sure you have warnings turned on. Do you get any?

Comment: these  are the warnings
   Notice: Use of undefined constant usertable - assumed 'usertable' in C:\xampp\htdocs\nn\login.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined variable: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\nn\login.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined variable: pass in C:\xampp\htdocs\nn\login.php on line 22
Query didn't work. Query was empty

Comment: <?php
class users{
var $username;
var $password;
var $conection;
var $tablename=usertable;
 function mysqldb(){
$this->conection=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db($this->tablename);}
function insertdb(){$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $this->tablename values ('','$user','$pass')");
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result) die("Query didn't work. " . mysql_error());}}
$user1=new users;
$user1->username=$_POST["user"];
$user1->password=$_POST["pass"];
$user1->age=$_POST["user"];
$user1->mysqldb();
$user1->insertdb();
?>

Comment: @RasimFryal: You forgot the second set of changes.

Comment: i did not get u.wot kind of second set of changes?

Comment: @RasimFryal: `$user` should be `$this->username` and `$pass` should be `$this->password`. Also, I thought `usertable` was a constant, but it appears it's not. Put it in quotes.

Comment: user and pasword are the names given to the text boxes of username and password in the form

Comment: @RasimFryal: I realize that. If you'd just try and change them, maybe you'd see it works.

Comment: @mimtech yes i did it but still recieving "Query didn't work. Query was empty"could u plz update better structure of this class withou condsidering security and data cheking.i mean, keep it very simple

Comment: @RasimFryal: I didn't consider security and data checking. This is the absolute minimum to get it working, but it appears it's not for you. Are you sure the password is right? Are you sure `usertable` is the name of your table?